# How to keep accentuation in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, encoding

I am trying to execute some code in my pyspark project, but when I execute my code whith any word that has a special character this happens:

```py
sql = f"""
SELECT
    'cão' as teste,
    encode('cão', 'utf-8') as teste2
FROM minha_tabela
"""
table = spark.sql(sql)
table = table.cache()
table.show()
```

[image]

I tried to encode using `utf-8`, but I have no ideia how can I solve this problem. When I write the data in my database the accentuation is also wrong.

My pyspark version is 3.4

Comment: What if you use `SELECT 'cão' as teste, encode('cão', 'utf-8') as teste2` (omitting `from minha_tabela`)? For me, it returns right values `cão` and `[63 C3 A3 6F]` in `teste` and `teste2`, respectively…